# Creating long lasting metrics from OpenTelemetry traces

Tags: elasticsearch, metrics, trace, open-telemetry, jaeger

I plan on adding OpenTelemetry to my service to produce traces and out of those traces I also want to generate metrics based on their attributes. Those metrics need to be long lasting as they will support some business decisions.
My initial idea is to use the OTEL Collector to receive traces and then export them to Jaeger and Elasticsearch.
I want to display then metrics with either Kibana or Grafana, but first I need to generate these metrics using the traces information.
Ideally I would be able to remove old traces and still keep the metrics related to those old traces.
Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the spanmetrics connector to produce metrics from traces: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/connector/spanmetricsconnector. The readme contains information on how to configure it in the OpenTelemetry Collector. Would this work for your use-case?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am already using the SpanMetrics processor to calculate to generate metrics about spans' durations. It would be great if it could also be used to generate custom metrics.